# Guava cache asMap method

Tags: java, guava

I have guava cache with store userId to mutex cache.

```
Cache<Long, Object> byUserIdMutex = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .concurrencyLevel(4)
       .weakKeys()
       .maximumSize(10000)
       .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .build();



private Object getMutex(long userId) {
    Object newLock = new Object();
    Object old = byUserIdMutex.asMap().putIfAbsent(userId, newLock);
    if (old != null) {
        return old;
    }
    return newLock;
}
```

Then I'm using synchronized section with mutex object. I expect that same user from different threads will be wait for another task by same key to be completed.

Let's say if I have thread 1

```
synchronized (getMutex(1)) {
}
```

Then thread 2 will wait for thread 1 to leave synchronized before finished execution, but it turns out that it does not happen, threads are not waiting for each other.

Maybe I have a race when converting guava cache to map using asMap() method ?

Comment: Consider instead using Guava's `Striped` for locking, instead of a cache.

Comment: @BenManes does not suit for me. Even if I create Striped with enough stripes (locks) inside, I may have a collision, when different users are waiting for each other.

Comment: A large lazy weak stripe is a weak valued map. So that, or doing the same directly, would be a safer eviction policy.

Comment: @BenManes It's not about eviction policy, I'm talking about collision. No matter how many stipes you have, you may have a collision, depending oh hash function. Please see Striped docs - "Note that if key1 is not equal to key2, it is not guaranteed that striped.get(key1) != striped.get(key2); the elements might nevertheless be mapped to the same lock" By using regular map as lock holder I will never have a collision. Having collision is completely unacceptable for my design.

Comment: Yes. As I said, a large lazy weak stripe is a map. And using the same directly (a weak valued map) would ensure no collisions explicitly. A policy that evicts while a lock is in use would allow two threads to execute for the same key. A weak reference to the lock ensures it is discarded when no one is using it. A weak key may not have the desired behavior as it uses reference equality, so two equivalent keys but different instances will map to two different locks. The weak value is safer than using weak keys, size, or expiration per your code snippet.

Comment: Since your method takes a primitive and boxes it, you will almost always receive a new lock due to using weak keys. Then you are relying on the JLS cache range, which is a jvm configuration, that by default is only 255 entries. I doubt that was intentional...

Comment: @BenManes ok, I did not even noticed weakKeys() line of code. Weak keys is an issue. Of course I did not want to rely on JVM cache Long values in range 255. If I remove weakKeys() line is there any reason to use huge Striped(guava weak value map) instead of LoadingCache despite better code looking. Btw weak keys should be accepted answer

Comment: Nope, as you said using the cache is more explicit. But I do think weak values as the only eviction policy is ideal, so you should favor that over size and expiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside your locking mechanism (as [@BenManes mentioned in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369219/guava-cache-asmap-method/42370046?noredirect=1#comment71898875_42369219), see if [`Striped`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html) isn't [better for your use case](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StripedExplained)), you should use [`LoadingCache`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html) here:

```
LoadingCache<Long, Object> byUserIdMutex = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .concurrencyLevel(4)
        .weakKeys()
        .maximumSize(10000)
        .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build(CacheLoader.from(Object::new));

private Object getMutex(long userId) {
    return byUserIdMutex.getUnchecked(userId);
}
```

This way you'll not have any race conditions, since [`getUnchecked`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#getUnchecked-K-) contract is:

> Returns the value associated with key in this cache, first loading that value if necessary. No observable state associated with this cache is modified until loading completes.

Plus, method `getMutex` would be probably redundant.

Comment: fyi, you can write the loader as a one-liner using `CacheLoader.from(function)`, which plays nicely with lambdas.

Comment: @BenManes Thanks, when I wrote the code above I wondered if such thing should exist in Guava, and it does! It also supports `CacheLoader.from(supplier)` so `Object::new` fits well, too.

Comment: Oddly `from(supplier)` forces an `Object` key, so sadly its not very useful as is.